# Select an image contains a special class - pure javascript

Tags: javascript, select, ecmascript-6

I have this HTML structure and gave image **src** to each `<img>` with javascript. Now, what I need is **select `<img>` with a click**, **give the selected image a class like `.active`** and **if I click on another image to select it, remove `.active` from other `<img>` and gave the active class to it**.

---

***HTML:***

```
<div class="images d-flex flex-wrap my-4">
    <div class="smallImages">
        <img id="bgImage1" src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="smallImages">
        <img id="bgImage2" src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="smallImages">
        <img id="bgImage3" src="" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

***Javascript:***

```
const imgThumbnail = document.querySelectorAll('.smallImages');

for ( let i = 1; i <= imgThumbnail.length; i++ ) {
  let imgId = document.querySelector('#bgImage'+ i + '');
  let imgSrc = imgId.src = './img/bg' + i + '.jpg';
}
```

---

***If it helps, my images src are like this:***

```
./img/bg1.jpg
./img/bg2.jpg
...
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I am not sure why that code is relevant now I look at it

Comment: I don't see any click events, nor anything adding or removing classes, etc. You'll have to make an attempt before asking us to help you out. The code you've included in your question, as @mplungjan points out, seems to have minimal relevance to what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I prefer saving the active element as a variable so you can directly remove the class from the previous one and add it to the new one without the need to loop over all images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the image clicked and add the class to the clicked image's classList.

I use onclick, you can use addEventListener if you need.

```js
var saveImage = "";
document.querySelector(".images").onclick=function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName=="IMG") {
    if (saveImage) saveImage.classList.remove("active");
    e.target.classList.add("active");
    saveImage = e.target;
  }
}
```

```css
.active { border: 1px solid red }
```

```html
<div class="images d-flex flex-wrap my-4">
    <div class="smallImages">
        <img id="bgImage1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=1" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="smallImages">
        <img id="bgImage2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=2" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="smallImages">
        <img id="bgImage3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=3" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Very very helpful, thanks a lot**. I working on this since yesterday and try many ways but I'm a beginner at Javascript :))

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```js
const imgThumbnail = [...document.querySelectorAll('.smallImages img')];

// setup src and events
imgThumbnail.forEach((img,index)=>{
  img.src = `./img/bg${index+1}.jpg`;
  img.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    const current = imgThumbnail.find(img=>img.matches('.active'));
    current && current.classList.remove('active');
    this.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

```css
img{width:50px;height:50px;background:gray;display:inline-block;}
.active{border:3px solid red;}
```

```html
<div class="images d-flex flex-wrap my-4">
    <div class="smallImages">
        <img id="bgImage1" src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="smallImages">
        <img id="bgImage2" src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="smallImages">
        <img id="bgImage3" src="" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note the above is not compatible with IE without polyfill. I suggest just blindly remove the class

Comment: @mplungjan well the question is tagged  [tag:ecmascript-6] so i excluded IE from the start :)

Comment: Ah, apologies - missed that. I suspect OP might not be aware of the consequences